# How to make my application still running after restart

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Login application that will disable after 3 times of wrong attempts..I just wanted to know how to make that application still running after i restart my computer..my application is already in .exe ...thanks in advance :)

Comment: It won't be **still running** regardless of any steps you take. The question is, at what point do you want the application to start? ***Top Hint*** You can't make an .exe file run before logon. (there are some caveats to top hint)

Comment: for example my system was disabled because of 3 times of wrong attempt..when i restart my computer i want my system to be still disabled and the time was still running.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Going on the assumption that you're talking about Windows here, a simple google search for "windows run application at startup" would yield a plethora of simple ways to make an application run when the OS starts.

Here is one of those results...

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7

Comment: hi sir,thanks for the answer ..does it make my application still running on the current process after i restart my computer ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can add application executable in windows startup. Following method help to create app shortcut.

```
    public static void CreateStartupShortcut(string applicationName)
    {
        string _startupFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);
        WshShell _shell = new WshShell();
        //
        string _shortcutAddress = _startupFolder + @"\" + applicationName + ".lnk";
        IWshShortcut _shortcut = (IWshShortcut)_shell.CreateShortcut(_shortcutAddress);
        _shell.RegDelete(_shortcutAddress);
        //
        _shortcut.Description = "Start up shortcut link for application " + applicationName + ". Delete shortcut to if you dont want to run application on stat up";
        _shortcut.WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
        _shortcut.TargetPath = Application.ExecutablePath;
        _shortcut.Save();
    }
```

Simply pass your application `exe` path to the method and it will add shortcut in windows startup.

Comment: thanks sir..is these codes would make my application still running from the last process it was doing before it restart?

Comment: @AdrianneMarco Once you create a shortcut of application, your application will automatically run when window is started or restated.